# Is it possible in case of function?

Tags: functions

I have been recently learning concept of Into/Onto functions. My instructor said if codomain is a subset of range then it is not a function. I need some example so as to when this may happen and why it will not be function

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:\{1,2\} \to \{1\}$, $f(x) = x$. See the contradiction? $f(2) "=" 2$, but $2 \not \in \{1\}$, so our function is ill-defined.

In general, the co-domain tells us 1) what sort of objects the function returns, and 2) gives a set such that $range(f)$ is a subset. In general, finding the actual range of a function may be computationally very complex. Having a co-domain allows us to bypass this difficulty.

**Edit**

Note that we can have the range of $f$ and the codomain be equal (in which case both are subsets of each other), but the codomain can't be a *proper subset* of the "range."